# Can i use pdfkit in a google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf in a google cloud function using pdfkit module from python.

This module pdfkit is a wrapper for wkhtmltopdf. I put the pdfkit in requirements.txt but i still need wkhtmltopdf.

Is it possible to use this module in google cloud functions?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to follow the steps in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#packaging_local_dependencies) to specify the dependencies properly.

You will basically have to package wkhtmltopdf locally and deploy it alongside your function since it cannot be directly installed using pip.